# Xamarin: Dynamically building a grid

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin

I'm a newer Xamarin/C# developer and am currently building an app that will display services of various businesses. I am looking for advice on how to dynamically build a grid based on the number of services a business offers. For instance, one business could offer 10 services, while another could offer 3, so I'd like to build a grid on the front end that adds on rows based on the number of services the business has to offer.

I currently have the following cs files : "BusinessService.cs" and "ServicesViewModel.cs".

Here is the BusinessService.cs file :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace One.Models
{
    public class BusinessService
    {

        public string ServiceName { get; set; }

        public decimal ServicePrice { get; set; }

   }
}
```

Here is the ServicesViewModel.cs file:

```
using One.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Text;

namespace One.ViewModel
{
    class ServicesViewModel
    {
        readonly IList<BusinessService> source;

        public ObservableCollection<BusinessService> ViewServices { get; private set; }


        public ServicesViewModel()
        {
            source = new List<BusinessService>();
            CreateServiceCollection();

        }

        void CreateServiceCollection()
        {
            source.Add(new BusinessService
            {
                ServiceName = "Dryer Vent Cleaning",
                ServicePrice = 100
            });

            source.Add(new BusinessService
            {
                ServiceName = "Gutter Cleaning",
                ServicePrice = 150
            });

            source.Add(new BusinessService
            {
                ServiceName = "Duct Cleaning",
                ServicePrice = 300
            });


            ViewServices = new ObservableCollection<BusinessService>(source);
             }
           }
       }
```

I understand that I'd have to build a function that would return the number of objects stored in the array, but I'm unsure how to do this and where to start. If I'm dynamically building the grid, would I have to build the entire grid in C# or could I pass something through and bind it to the building done on the XAML side?

Comment: `I understand that I'd have to build a function that [...]`: where do you understand that from? Did you follow a tutorial or made any attempt? Also, my unserstanding is that `Grid` is not collection-friendly and that you should consider using a `DataGrid` instead.

Comment: use CollectionView - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/layout#vertical-grid

Comment: @CorentinPane This is advice I received through word of mouth but was unsuccessful at adapting it. Thanks for the advice! I will try this.

Comment: @Jason How would I define the dynamic build with CollectionView?

Comment: assign an ItemsSource and build a template.  This is explained in the docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I understand that I'd have to build a function that would return the number of objects stored in the array, but I'm unsure how to do this and where to start. If I'm dynamically building the grid, would I have to build the entire grid in C# or could I pass something through and bind it to the building done on the XAML side?

If you want to display different amount services,as everyone said that you need to use collection-control to display data, for example, Listview, CollectionView...

I do one sample about using CollectionView to display data, you can take a look:

ViewModel.cs:

```
public class ServicesViewModel:ViewModelBase
{
    public ObservableCollection<BusinessService> source { get; set; }

    public ServicesViewModel()
    {
        source = new ObservableCollection<BusinessService>();
    }

}
```

ContentPage.xaml:

```
<StackLayout>
        <CollectionView x:Name="collectionview1" ItemsSource="{Binding source}">
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackLayout>
                        <Label Text="{Binding ServiceName}" />
                        <Label Text="{Binding ServicePrice}" />
                    </StackLayout>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>

        <Button
            x:Name="btnget"
            Clicked="btnget_Clicked"
            Text="get data" />
    </StackLayout>
```

ContentPage.cs:

```
 public partial class Page10 : ContentPage
{
    List<BusinessService> list;      
    public ServicesViewModel servicesmodel { get; set; }    

    public Page10()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        servicesmodel = new ServicesViewModel();

        this.BindingContext = servicesmodel;
    }

    private void btnget_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        //get data from web api or other way to display in collectionview.
        list = new List<BusinessService>();

        list.Add(new BusinessService() {ServiceName="service 1",ServicePrice=Convert.ToDecimal(12.44)  });
        list.Add(new BusinessService() { ServiceName = "service 2", ServicePrice = Convert.ToDecimal(12.44) });
        list.Add(new BusinessService() { ServiceName = "service 3", ServicePrice = Convert.ToDecimal(12.44) });
        list.Add(new BusinessService() { ServiceName = "service 4", ServicePrice = Convert.ToDecimal(12.44) });
        list.Add(new BusinessService() { ServiceName = "service 5", ServicePrice = Convert.ToDecimal(12.44) });
        list.Add(new BusinessService() { ServiceName = "service 6", ServicePrice = Convert.ToDecimal(12.44) });

        if(list!=null)
        {

            foreach(BusinessService service in list)
            {
                servicesmodel.source.Add(service);
            }
        }       
    }      
}
```

You can get different amount services by web api or other way, then add Observablecollection to display.

About using CollectionView or ListView, please take a look:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/populate-data

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/data-and-databinding